# Is it possible to use regex with search parameter in CalendarApp.getEvents()?

Tags: regex, google-apps-script, google-calendar-api

I'm trying to filter my Google Calendar events by name using [getEvents(startTime, endTime, options)](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/calendar/calendar-app#getEvents(Date,Date,Object)), but need to exclude some special events.

```
var events = cal.getEvents(new Date("September 27, 2019 00:00:00 CST"), new Date("February 18, 2020 23:59:59 CST"), {search: 'MyEvent.*(VO|UE)'});
```

Is there a way to only get Events that contain "MyEvent", but also "VO" or "UE"?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As of now, it is not possible to query your events with the API or with Apps Script.

However, you could achieve this by filtering the information with the `filter()` function.

It would look like this:

```
function myFunction() {
  var cal = CalendarApp.getDefaultCalendar();
  var events = cal.getEvents(new Date("September 27, 2019 00:00:00 CST"), new Date("February 18, 2020 23:59:59 CST"), {search: 'MyEvent'}); //Still searching for MyEvent since that needs to be always present.
  var filteredEvents = events.filter(function  (event) {
                                     return event.getTitle().match('MyEvent.*(VO|UE)')!==null;
                                     });
  Logger.log(filteredEvents.map(function(event) { return event.getTitle(); }));
}
```

I hope this helps you!

Comment: Thanks, that looks exactly like what I need, but unfortunately there seems to be a Syntax error on the second line. I can't find the problem (I just started learning Javascript and don't know Google script at all), do you see an obvious typo?

Comment: @JohannesPertl sorry for the delayed update. I have updated the answer to be correct.

Comment: Thank you! In the meantime, I solved my problem semi manually, but maybe it helps someone in the future :D

Answer (score -1):

I'm not sure about regular expressions, but you might be able to leverage the optional [**q** parameter](https://developers.google.com/calendar/v3/reference/events/list/#q) of the Calendar API's `Events.list` endpoint to perform a Free Text search.

Use of the term is [primarily documented under the Drive API](https://developers.google.com/drive/api/v3/search-files) but those guides should be applicable (at least in part) to the Calendar API as well.

Note that you'll have to leverage either the [Advanced Service](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/guides/services/advanced) for Google Calendar or query the Calendar REST API directly using `UrlFetchApp.fetch()`.

Comment: The definition of the q parameter for the Drive API does not apply to the Calendar API. For the Calendar API, the q parameter is defined as "Free text search terms to find events that match these terms in any field, except for extended properties."